JWT tokens with different expiration times based on user roles in Symfony
I'm working on a Symfony project where I handle authentication using JWT tokens, generated with the LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle. I need to create tokens with different expiration times depending on the user's role. Specifically:

If the user has the ROLE_WEBAPP, the token should be valid for 1.5 days.

If the user has the ROLE_QLIKSENS, the token should be valid for 1 year.

For all other roles, the token should have a default expiration time like 1 hour.


I've already configured the bundle and it works well with a fixed token_ttl, but I haven't found a way to dynamically adjust the token's lifetime based on the user's role.

this might be helpful as well
